# Invalid URI for Localhost

Tags: asp.net

We have a website/webservice running on one of our servers. We hit that webservice once a day with a scheduled .bat scipt.

Just recently the scheduled task started to fail. The log shows "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."

When we're logged into the server we can reach the website through http://localhost/website, but get an Invalid URI error when we hit the webservice http://localhost/website/ws.asmx.

Any ideas?

**Edit**:

We'be tried using the servername, the ipaddress, and port numbers (and combinations therein). Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you intend to leave off the 'http:' from your URLs? Because they're not valid without it.

Comment: @Arachnid, we did specify http: I edited the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the private IP Address your using Wikipedia Reference  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address for what are the limits and proper uses.

If you have access to the source code for the web service look for fixed IP Address being used along with having correct Server Bindings for using the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IP Address of the machine instead of localhost.

Basically, I'm taking a wild stab that someone ran a lockdown or a service patch was installed that somehow is filtering request resposes to localhost (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the machine name instead of localhost